# Different table formatting in editor and outside

Tags: bug, editor, formatting, tables

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65253949/3157428) badly formatted answer and wanted to edit it to correct the formatting.

The table formatting is messed as can be seen:

[image: Bad formatting]

However when I click edit, formatting is OK:

[image: Looks fine]

Is there something obvious I cannot spot?

Even if there is some mistake as no newline that I can't see, this should not be as it is. If you post properly formatted table in editor it should stay like that in post. I consider this being bug. Am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe the user posted it like that before markdown tables were enabled? And now, since you're editing it after markdown tables are enabled, you see the nice new shiny?

Comment: user posted it one hour ago.

Comment: Add a blank line before the table starts

Comment: I thought it is something like that, but inconsistency of rendering in editor and after posting is not really good stuff, I still consider it as bug, the poster believes he is posting good content and it gets messed after posting.

Comment: This is already mentioned on the Tables announcement on MSE so it's on our list of things to investigate.

Comment: Good to hear @Catija, thanks for letting me know. For now will set just by new line until it is solved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The implementation of the Markdown parsers differ between the client and the server. The client one seems less picky.

If weird stuff happens, try adding a blank line first. An extra blank line helps the parser determine the correct start of new markdown.

The extra blank line was the trick that solved this issue. I made that edit for you.

There is a [bug report on the MSE Table announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596/158100) for this specific issue.