# Question preview shows one thing but the end result is different

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

### What is happening

I just realised my answer was being wrongly rendered. The title is rendered as `### title` and not in the correct format.

[image: Result]

I went to edit it, but the preview shows it the way I was expecting. Saving it doesn't change anything.

[image: Editing the answer]

---

### Reproducible here

---

#### <strike>1. *(Stopped working)* Use function as `useEffect` callback</strike>

```
useEffect(fetchBusinesses, [])
```

### 2. Declare function inside `useEffect()`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  function fetchBusinesses() {
    ...
  }
  fetchBusinesses()
}, [])
```

---

### Expected behavior

The Preview should be the same as the end result. And the end result should render correctly.

There is one question for a similar issue, but what fixed that doesn't fix this one (I tried editing the post and saving again).
[Final answer rendering is different in the editor preview](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405497/final-answer-rendering-is-different-in-the-editor-preview)

Comment: You have a [steady hand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) for those circles ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issue** - There are (2) whitespace characters above the header:

### 2. Declare function inside `useEffect()`

---

**Suggestion** - No whitespace characters above the header:

#### 2. Declare function inside `useEffect()`

---

Note: As detailed in the question, this is currently a bug in the preview that shows both the above in the expected format however the live page does not render the heading with whitespace above. Here is a GIF for clarification and future reference:

[image: 1]

Comment: Nevertheless, the preview should show the same as the final display.

Comment: @BDL: Yes! It's a bug just like when creating a [Table without a blank line above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403575/different-table-formatting-in-editor-and-outside); just wanted to point out why the issue only seemed to be in `2.` but not `1.`

Comment: True, the preview should be the same, but this solves the display error, thanks =D